# RequestWrapper objects must extend ServletRequestWrapper or HttpServletRequestWrapper

Tags: java, websphere, runtime-error

I am using encoded forms from "EAR A" to "EAR B".

When I try to process the request:

```
    accion = "/decimprenta";
    pagina = "/procesardeclaracion.do";
    this.getServlet().getServletContext().getContext(accion).getRequestDispatcher(pagina).forward(request, response);
```

the "EAR A" throws the following exception:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: SRV.8.2: RequestWrapper objects must extend ServletRequestWrapper or HttpServletRequestWrapper
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.util.ServletUtil.unwrapRequest(ServletUtil.java:91)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.util.ServletUtil.unwrapRequest(ServletUtil.java:63)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.util.ServletUtil.unwrapRequest(ServletUtil.java:58)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1127)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:191)
```

Browsing, I found this link with the same error, but the patches are version 6 of WAS. I am using WAS 8:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM10357

Any idea?

Comment: Could you post fragments of your code so we can take a look at it?

Answer (score 2):

What version of Struts are you using? If you are using 1.2.7 or later then you will see this error.
I had this problem when I was using

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

This is because when you are using MultipartRequestWrapper.  In version 1.2.* the [MultipartRequestWrapper](http://struts.apache.org/release/1.2.x/api/org/apache/struts/upload/MultipartRequestWrapper.html) extended java.lang.Object

In 1.3.* the [MultiPartRequestWrapper](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/struts/struts-1.3.10/org/apache/struts/upload/MultipartRequestWrapper.java.html) extends HttpServletRequestWrapper

I found this same problem with WAS 8.5, but updating the struts solved the issue.

Hope this helps